# Jenkins CI configuration on Ubuntu for multiple access over the internet

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I just set up a jenkins instance on an ubuntu VM, everything works well as I am able to access it via http://localhost:8080, however, I am trying to enable access to the server by multiple users on multiple hosts within the LAN and even outside the LAN. What is the best way to achieve this?

Modifying the "URL" via "Configure System" link on Jenkins Dashboard isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with an nginx reverse proxy, that will also handle your SSL offloading.

here is an excellent tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-jenkins-with-ssl-using-an-nginx-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I was later able to fix this problem by the same method i was trying before i.e modifying the "URL" via "Configure System" link on Jenkins Dashboard. It wasnt working before because I had a firewall rule restricting access via port 8080